# Fullcalendar and livewire. Trying to edit newly created events

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar, laravel-livewire

I`m trying to use fullcalendar with livewire. I'm following this article:

https://barryvdh.nl/laravel/livewire/fullcalendar/2020/10/24/using-fullcalendar-with-laravel-livewire/

The issue i'm facing is that when I create a new event, if I try to edit it inmediatly with dragging and dropping or resizing it, there is no 'id' field and then it can't be selected from the DB. If I refresh the page everything works as expected.

I have tried to use `calendar.refetchEvents()`, because in the laravel debug bar I can see that the array of data from de DB is already updated, but it doesn't works.

I have tried too returning the id after creating the new event in de DB and then adding it to the fullcalendar event, but shows "object promise" and didn`t retrieve de id.

It's Laravel 9.

Thanks for the help.

Calendar.blade.php:

```
<div id='calendar-container' wire:ignore>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
@push('scripts')
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
            var draggedEl = FullCalendar.Draggable;
            // new way to init full calendar in v5
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var checkbox = document.getElementById('drop-remove');
            var containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events');
            var data = @this.events;
            new draggedEl(containerEl, {
                itemSelector: '.fc-event',
                eventData: function (eventEl) {
                    return {
                        title: eventEl.innerText
                    };
                },
                title: this.innerText,
            });
            @this.on(`refreshCalendar`, () => {
                calendar.refetchEvents();
                 alert('RefetchingEvents...');
            });
            // store calendar reference in global variable like below so you can use it later.
            var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
                slotMinTime: '09:00:00',
                slotMaxTime: '22:00:00',
                slotDuration: '00:15:00',
                slotLabelInterval: '00:15:00',
                editable: true,
                selectable: true,
                eventDurationEditable: true,
                displayEventTime: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },
                events: JSON.parse(data),
                dateClick(info) {
                    var title = prompt('Enter Event Title');
                    var date = info.dateStr;
                    var end = date+'T00:02:00'
                    if (title != null && title != '') {
                        var eventAdd = {title: title, start: date, end:end};
                       @this.addevent(eventAdd);
                        calendar.addEvent({
                            title: title,
                            start: date,
                            end: end,
                            });
                    } else {
                        alert('Event Title Is Required');
                    }
                    //info.event.id = id;
                },
                drop: function (info) {  // external draggable element or an event from another calendar
                    var title = info.draggedEl.innerText;
                    var date = info.dateStr;
                    var end = date+'T00:02:00'
                    var eventAdd = {title: title, start: date, end:end};
                    @this.addevent(eventAdd);
                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if (checkbox.checked) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
                    }
                },
                eventDrop: info => @this.eventDrop(info.event, info.oldEvent), //The event has moved to a different day/time.

                eventResize: info => @this.eventResize(info.event, info.oldEvent),

            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.11.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
@endpush
```

Calendar.php

```
    <?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Event;
class Calendar extends Component
{
    public $events = '';
    public function getevent()
    {
        $events = Event::select('id','title','start','end')->get();
        return  json_encode($events);
    }
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function addevent($event)
    {
        $input['title'] = $event['title'];
        $input['start'] = $event['start'];
        $input['end'] = $event['end'];
        Event::create($input);
        $this->emit("refreshCalendar");
    }
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function eventDrop($event, $oldEvent)
    {
//        dd($event,$oldEvent);
        $eventdata = Event::find($event['id']);
        $eventdata->start = $event['start'];
        $eventdata->end = $event['end'];
        $eventdata->save();
    }
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function eventResize($event, $oldEvent)
    {
        $eventdata = Event::find($event['id']);
        $eventdata->start = $event['start'];
        $eventdata->end = $event['end'];
        $eventdata->save();
    }
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $events = Event::select('id','title','start','end')->get();
        $this->events = json_encode($events);
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a solution emiting an event from my component after storing the event in the database, and after that creating the fullcalendar event.

Component:

```
public function addevent($event)
{
    $input['title'] = $event['title'];
    $input['start'] = $event['start'];
    $input['end'] = $event['end'];
    $event = Event::create($input);
    $this->emit('eventAdded', ['id' => $event->id,'title' => $event->title,'start' => $event->start,'end' => $event->end]);
}
```

Blade:

```
@this.on(`eventAdded`, (event) => {
            calendar.addEvent({
                id: event.id,
                title: event.title,
                start: event.start,
                end: event.end,
            });
        });
```